# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> A sequence of polynomials is given by $$p_n(x) =a_{n+2}x^2 +a_{n+1}x-a_n$$ for
>   $n\geq 0$, where $a_0=a_1=1$ and for $n\geq 0$ $$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1} +a_n$$ Denote by $r_n$ and $s_n$ the roots of $p_n(x)=0$, with $r_n\leq s_n$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n$.

---

This is a Fibonacci sequence because for $n\geq 0$,$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1} +a_n$ and $a_0=a_1=1$ is a definition of Fibonacci sequence.
It is also clear that $x=-1$ is a root of the equation $$p_n(x) =a_{n+2}x^2 +a_{n+1}x-a_n$$
So it is clear that $\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n=-1$. But I cannot find $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n.$

What should I do? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use sum of roots and product of roots.

For a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with roots $s, t$, we have $s+t=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $st=\frac{c}{a}$.

Since we already have $1$ root, we can substitute it into the product of roots equation: $s_nr_n=\frac{-a_n}{a_{n+2}}$

Hence $s_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+2}}$.

Since Fibonacci numbers increase exponentially, i.e.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$

we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\times\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{-2}=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}\times\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2(3-\sqrt{5})}{4}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Can i get the proof of this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$?

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia  Are you familiar with the formula with Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Edited.

Comment: I got it,nice explanation +1,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. We know that $a_n=c_1w_1^n+c_2w_2^n$, where 
$$
w_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\quad w_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
Hence $r_n\to r$ and $s_n\to s$, where $r,s$ are the roots of
$$
w_1^2x^2+w_1x-1=0.
$$

Comment: See here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html